# Puting a new element at the begining of the list

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hy Guys!
So my problem is that I don't see anything bad in this code.

```
type Name = String

type Val = Either Int Bool
type Env = [(Name, Val)]    

update :: Name -> Val -> Env -> Env -> Env
    update x v [] origi = (x,v): origi
    update x v ((x', v'):xs) origi
      | x == x'   = (x, v):xs
      | otherwise = (x', v') : update x v xs origi
```

But any time I call it happens to duplicate the first elements. I believe it doesn't check the last element of the list, but I don't get it where I miss it.

So what I want to do here. Is updating elements in the list which are there. But if they are not in the list. I want to put them at the begining. Puting them at the end would be easy I know.

Comment: Why are there two `Env` parameters? I would only expect one.

Comment: One is for stroing the original lsit, and other one is to get through the List element by element

Comment: I don't think that should be part of the external interface of the function. It can handle that detail internally with a helper function.

Comment: I don't get this one sorry :(

Comment: So should I just skip storing the original list in a variable?

Comment: Also there's no need to remember the original anyway.

Comment: Then how can I put the new element at the begining of the list, if I ended up with an empty list?

Comment: Does it actually have to go at the beginning? It's easier to put it at the end. And your current implementation can't guarantee it goes in the beginning anyway, because you may replace an entry that's in the middle.

Comment: In order for us to know what's wrong with your code, you need to actually explain what your code is supposed to be doing. You need to be much more specific than "updating elements in the list which are there", since there are two different lists passed as input to `update` and it's not clear how you want to "update" elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you gave `update` the wrong type. The type should instead be

```hs
update :: Name -> Val -> Env -> Env
```

A simple implementation would be

```hs
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

update :: Name -> Val -> Env -> Env
update name val env = 
    let newEnvIfAbsent = (name, val) : env
        tryToModify list = case list of
            [] -> Nothing
            (name', val') : rest -> if name' == name 
                                    then Just $ (name, val) : rest
                                    else fmap ((name', val') :) $ tryToModify rest
    in fromMaybe newEnvIfAbsent $ tryToModify env
```

Informally, we try to modify `env` by finding a pair of the form `(name : val')` and replacing this with `(name, val)`. If this is unsuccessful, we instead append  `(name, val)` to the beginning of `env`.

We can improve the performance of the algorithm somewhat (though not its asymptotic complexity) by, ironically, avoiding the use of `Maybe` as follows:

```hs
update name val env =
    let newEnvIfAbsent = (name, val) : env
        tryToModify list = case list of
            [] -> ([], False)
            (name', val') : rest -> if name' == name
                                    then ((name, val) : rest, True)
                                    else let (rem, suc) = tryToModify rest
                                          in ((name', val') : rem, suc)
        (modifyResult, succeeded) = tryToModify env
    in if succeeded then modifyResult else newEnvIfAbsent
```

In the second implementation, we don't have to pass information about the success or failure back up the stack. Thus, we're less vulnerable to stack overflow.